# What is the default Foreground color of a WPF GridViewItem control?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, colors, foreground

In WPF, if you use a ListView control with the View set to a GridView, the default Foreground color of the items are dark blue. What is the actual brush value used for it? I've looked into the default templates of ListViewitem, GridViewItem, etc. but I couldn't figure out where the Foreground color is set. I'd appreciate any pointer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

That's probably `#FF042271`, which is found in the default GridView-Style.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#FF042271"/>
```

The default styles can be downloaded [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), follow the link in the second paragraph.